# A particular double "for" loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

$bar contains 4 (in this example, but potentially much more than 4) values I want to copy into $foo and $blah in this way:

```
$foo[0] = $bar[0];
$foo[1] = $bar[2];
$blah[0] = $bar[1];
$blah[1] = $bar[3];
```

So, the even rows of $bar will be copied into $foo[i], and the odd rows will be copied into $blah[i].

I tried with:

```
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j<4; $j++)
    {  
        if($j % 2 == 0)
            {  
            $foo[$i] = $bar[$j]; // EVEN
            }
            else
            {
            $blah[$i] = $bar[$j];  // ODD
        }
    }
}
```

However if I show the output of $foo and $blah, $foo[0] is equal to $foo[1], and $blah[0] is equal to $blah[1], while they should contain different values.

Example:
Source:

```
$bar[0]: 27.8
$bar[1]: Napoli-Posillipo
$bar[2]: 29
$bar[3]: Stadio San Paolo di Napoli, Napoli
```

(wrong) result of the loop:

```
$foo[0] = 29 (it should be 27.8)  
$foo[1] = 29
$blah[0] = Stadio San Paolo di Napoli, Napoli (it should be Napoli-Posillipo)
$blah[1] = Stadio San Paolo di Napoli, Napoli
```

Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: You **need to indent your code properly**!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you have made it to complex, something simple like this should work:

```
foreach ($bar as $k=>$v){
    if($k % 2 == 0){  
         $foo[] = $v; // EVEN
    }else{
         $blah[] = $v;  // ODD
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just thinking "I see no need for a double for-loop". You were a few minutes faster :)

Comment: You're right, there was something weird into that double loop... your solution works great. :)

Answer (score 3):

what about sth like

```
foreach($bar as $key => $value) {
   if($key % 2 == 0) {
      //even
      $foo[] = $value;
   }
   else {
      // odd
      $blah[] = $value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep, both of you suggested the same solution. Thanks to you, too :)

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself:

"So, the even rows of $bar will be copied into $foo[i], and the odd rows will be copied into $blah[i]".

Cycle all $bar, and copy odd rows into $blah, even into $foo:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
  if ($i % 2)
     $blah[$i/2] = $bar[$i];
  else
     $foo[$i/2] = $foo[$i];
```

In the general case:

```
  switch($i % N) // "N" for Napoli :-D
  {
     case 0: $VAR1[$i/N] = $bar[$i]; break;
     case 1: $VAR2[$i/N] = $bar[$i]; break;
     ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, the whole problem is clear now, I guess I didn't manage to correctly transform into working code what I had into my mind.